# What to name a class with few properties and no methods whose instances get passed around a lot?

Tags: oop, naming-conventions

I have several small classes that are similar in that they only possess a few properties and no methods, and their instances often get passed around and put into arrays and what not. Is there a naming convention for such a class? At first I was naming them xxxObject, but in OOP that's not really what an object is. Then I considered naming them xxxHelper, but helper seems to indicate methods. What should I add on to the end of this type of class's name?

Answer (score 0):

I would not make these classes at all, it looks like you're using some kind of a global enum or a dictionary.

Enum from C would indicate a key and an integer value.

Dictionary from Python would indicate key and value, value doesn't have to be a specific type.

I would probably use XXDictionary.